# In .NET, why does SerialPort.ReadExisting() return a String instead of a byte array?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

In the .NET [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class the `ReadExisting()` method returns a `String` instead of an array of bytes. This seems like an odd choice considering that RS232 is typically used to move 7 or 8 bit values, which may or may not be printable characters. Is there a reason for this choice?

Currently I end up using `System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes(recvd_data)` to convert the `String` to a byte array. Is there a more efficient method?

Comment: It looks like a convenience method, because there is also a `Read` method that reads into a `Char[]`.

Comment: The BaseStream property is the way to go, see http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used `SerialPort` extensively and the best way i've found to read a series of bytes is making multiple calls to `ReadByte()`. Yes, you read one byte at a time but i've found that keeping it simple has avoided problems.

At best, this method will save you from having to do a convert (since you'll read into a byte array).

Comment: Do you see any performance hit from this method? Serial is pretty slow, so I am guessing that its the limiting factor...

Comment: @JesseCraig I don't really notice any kind of performance issues and I read a lot of data from the serial port. It might be worthwhile in your case to test both of these methods and see which one performs better in your scenario.

Comment: @JesseCraig How did it go? Did you find this helped you out?

Comment: Yup, worked like a charm. I am reading from a ZigBee (mesh mode) which is only 9600 baud and I noticed no performance hit.

Answer (score 6):

`SerialPort` has a Read overload that reads into the specified `Byte[]`.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)